# firebase push notification add multiline to payload body

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

my firebase functions trigger and send to device a notification with this payload:

```
...
          notification: {
                    title: title,
                    body: "this is the content of first line: \n second line",
                    badge: "1",
                    sound: "default",
                  }
...
         return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, msg);
```

i need to separate the body content in 2 lines.
i tried with \r\n  or \n but when notification arrives to the device, this always show all the body content in one line.

some suggestion to do this correctly? thanks

Comment: In case there is no built-in support for this (which I don't know), you can try [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to display custom notifications - but I don't know how it works with background notifications.

Comment: thank you @PeterKoltai